# Steps to install Websphere Application Server Network Deployment

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have downloaded Websphere Application Server Network Deployment trial version as a http download in 3 parts. After unzipping those files I am clueless about its installation.

What are steps to install it on Windows 7 64bit machine?
If there is any link which explains these steps, please let me know. I am tired of googling it but unable to find any clean explanation of installation steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with WAS 8.0, WAS is installed with another program called [IBM Installation Manager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/welc_newinstaller.html). The three files you downloaded are collectively a WAS ND "repository". The high level steps are the following.

1. Download WAS ND (you've done this).
2. Unzip the three files, creating disk1, disk2, etc.  This is your repository.
3. Download IM.
4. Install IM.
5. Run IM.
6. Add your WAS ND repository to IM's set of repositories.
7. Install ND.

You can re-use the IM to apply fix packs, install other WebSphere related products, and remove these products.

Comment: I know it's an old thread but would like to ask since it's relevant to the question. Can we use same IM set up with a repository to install WAS ND on more than one machine/OS?

Answer (score 0):

The product documentation (infocenter) will tell you how to install it.  - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/welc6productov.html

Answer (score 0):

Though its an old thread but sometimes the IM gives lot of troubles for installing fix packs. So here is an alternative solution using command line that's pretty simple and to the point

- Download the fix packs [eg: part1, part2].
- Extract the packs in a single folder **fix_packXX**.
- Go to `<%WEBSHERE_HOME%>/AppServer/bin` and check the version details of the WAS by running following command in CMD:

```
versionInfo.bat
```

- Mark the following details[Especially the **Package** of WAS]:

```
Build Date            5/14/13
Package               com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERS.v85_8.5.5000.20130514_1044
```

- Go to

```
Windows: C:\Program Files\IBM\Installation Manager\eclipse\tools
Linux: opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/
```

- Run below command in CMD/BASH [Change the directory as per your path]:

```
Windows: imcl listAvailablePackages -repositories "C:/fix_packXX/repository.config"
Linux: ./imcl listAvailablePackages -repositories /fix_packXX/repository.config
```

- Choose the suitable **Package** [eg: DEVELOPERS in this case] to install by checking the type we noted in steps above. Run the command below with the new **Package** and let the package installation complete

```
imcl install com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERS.v85_8.5.5012.20170627_1018 -repositories "C:/fix_packXX/repository.config" -installationDirectory "<%WEBSHERE_HOME%>/AppServer" -acceptLicense -sP
```

- Done.

Hope that helps someone who is struggling with IBM Installation Manager.